# Twitter Java API: OAuth + REST calls

Tags: twitter

I can't make 350 requests (the maximum for the REST API) to the Twitter API, I can only make 150.

So I am getting tweet contents from tweet IDs:

```
url = new URL("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=" + tweetId + "&include_entities=true");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

And before this, I tried to authenticate with this:

```
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken(token);
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(tokenSecret);       
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
```

I suppose I should use the "twitter" variable to call the requests but I don't know how.

Thanks in advance,